# What are the typical qualification norms for assembly line workers?

Tags: production-testing

My question seems OFF-TOPIC, but I do believe there might be people **here**(at electronics_stackEx) who know the answer. And I really don't know a better place to post this.

Here Goes the question:
What kind of *education qualification* do *electronics* assembly line workers possess?

I don't know the nature of this kind of work.
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about employment qualifications for assembly line workers.

Comment: @JoeHass Can you please suggest me be *the* suitable place for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPC have international standard courses on assembly: http://www.eytraining.org.uk/t/Services/IPC-Training.aspx

> The five IPC certification programmes are:
>
> IPC A-610 Acceptability in Electronic Assemblies is for quality
>   assurance/visual acceptance of electronic assemblies based on the
>   world's most widely used electronics assembly acceptability standard
>
> IPC J-STD-001 Requirements for Soldered Electrical and Electronic
>   Assemblies is for hand and machine soldering processes and material
>   requirements. It includes hands-on training.
>
> IPC A-600 Acceptability of Printed Boards is for quality
>   assurance/visual acceptance of unpopulated printed circuit boards and
>   explores the specifications, problems and faults that occur with the
>   manufacture of PCBs.
>
> IPC/WHMA A-620 Requirements and Acceptance for Cable and Wire Harness
>   Assemblies is for improving the quality of your cables and harnesses,
>   reducing errors and costs.
>
> IPC 7711/7721 Rework, Modification and Repair of Electronic Assemblies
>   is for the rework, repair and modification of electronic assemblies,
>   rather than scrapping them. It features hands-on training.

Comment: Its very Helpful, I didn't knew this stuff before! It might sound silly but what's the *expansion* for *IPC*( I googled but results are confounding)?

Comment: Found [it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPC_(electronics))! Thanks.